# ¿Cómo no repetir una línea de código (Texto en este caso) dentro de un foreach?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo un foreach para mostrar resultados, en este caso uso Balde de Laravel, pero la respuesta de PHP me sirve, puedo adaptarla.

En el deseo mostrar un texto sin que se repita, ya que con mí código lo repite la cantidad de veces que hayan resultados... Lo quiero poner como título en segmentos de los resultados. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($user->type == 1)
        Resultados para usuario 1 // acá se muestran todas las coincidencias con los registros en la BD
    @elseif ($user->type == 2)
        Resultados para usuario 2 // acá se muestran todas las coincidencias con los registros en la BD
    @elseif ($user->type == 3)
        Resultados para usuario 3 // acá se muestran todas las coincidencias con los registros en la BD
    @elseif ($user->type == 4)
        Resultados para usuario 4 // acá se muestran todas las coincidencias con los registros en la BD         
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Lo que necesito es colocarle un título a cada segmento, sin que se repitan (No entre en el bucle), ejemplo:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($user->type == 1)
        Título para usuario 1 // sin que se repita
        Resultados para usuario 1 // acá se muestran todas las coincidencias con los registros en la BD
    @elseif ($user->type == 2)
        Título para usuario 2 // sin que se repita
        Resultados para usuario 2 // acá se muestran todas las coincidencias con los registros en la BD
    @elseif ($user->type == 3)
        Título para usuario 3 // sin que se repita
        Resultados para usuario 3 // acá se muestran todas las coincidencias con los registros en la BD
    @elseif ($user->type == 4)
        Título para usuario 4 // sin que se repita
        Resultados para usuario 4 // acá se muestran todas las coincidencias con los registros en la BD         
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Actualización:

Gracias por responder, y disculpa si no me expliqué bien, además coloqué un mal ejemplo con la tabla users, por eso la confusión. Ese código lo uso con blade de laravel, en dicha vista recojo una array que viene del controlador que contiene varios campos [id, name, type] de una base de datos. En name uso el nombre del producto y en type el tipo (Si es una herramienta, un servicio, etc) ... En cada if muestro los productos según su tipo y funciona bien, pero para diferenciarlos (Para el usuario) quiero darle un título a cada uno (Uno en cada if), pero se repite el título, el control no tiene una manera de decirle que esa línea de código que se encuentra dentro del if no se repita?

PD: Pensé que el ejemplo del user era más sencillo.

Comment: Lamentablemente tu pregunta no se entiende. Parecería que el asunto se podría resolver con un array asociativo, pero la pregunta es muy confusa...

Comment: No entiendo todavía. Lo que parece que quieres es poner una especie de encabezado por grupos o algo así ¿? Pon un pequeño ejemplo del resultado que esperas y di si los datos vienen ordenados o no. Si es lo que sospecho ese dato es importante de cara a una solución.

Comment: Sí necesito un encabezado en cada if, esos if están dentro de un foreach, si coloco el encabezado en cada grupo se repite por la cantidad de registros encontrados en la BD. Lo que necesito es que el título no se vea afectado por el bucle, existe un comando en php para obviarlo estando dentro de un bucle? osea, que no se repita esa línea, el resto si. Los datos ya vienen en la consulta ordenados alfabeticamente, y en cada if filtro el tipo de dato, ejemplo en un grupo herramientas, en el segundo servicios y así sucesivamente y yo quiero en cada grupo poner un título para diferenciarlos.

Comment: Una solución es hacer un foreach en cada if (en cada grupo) y dejar el título por fuera de cada bucle. Claro sino hay alguna opción, porque así se repite mucho código

Comment: Observa mi respuesta al final, donde dice  **EDICIÓN**. No sé si es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del metodo [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-groupby)  de laravel [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collection).

Pasarias de tu controlador a la vista esto: `$users->groupBy('type')`,  algo asi

```
public function index() 
{
     $users = \App\User::all(); // o de la forma que obtengas tu array

     $types = $users->groupBy('type');   // agrupará por tipo

     return view('myview', ['types' => $types])  
}
```

y en tu vista

```
@foreach($types as $k => $v)
    @if ($k == 1)     
      Título 1   
    @elseif($k == 2)
      Título 2
    @elseif($k == 3)
      Título 3
    @elseif($k == 4)
      Título 4
    @endif

    @foreach($v as $user)
        Resultados filtrados por tipo (usar  $user->field)
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Por lo que se mostraria:

```
Título 1
  Usuario de tipo 1
  Usuario de tipo 1
Título 2
  Usuario de tipo 2
  Usuario de tipo 2
  ...
Título 3
  Usuario de tipo 3
  ....
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentarlo!

Comment: La variable users del controllador se debe pasar a la vista?

Comment: Depende, si solo quieres mostrar en tu vista lo que preguntaste entonces ya no es necesario.

Comment: Por cierto, puedes agregar {{ $v->count() }} al lado de los titulos por si te interesa mostrar el numero de los usuarios que pertenecen a dicho tipo

Answer (score 2):

Entendiendo tu pregunta planteada así:

*Tengo un valor numérico, por ejemplo: 1, 2, 3, 4 ... y en base a ese valor quiero imprimir un contenido sin tener que hacer un bucle o hacer evaluaciones mediante condicionales como `if`.  ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?*

La respuesta es muy simple. Puedes manejar un array que contenga como claves los valores numéricos que tengas que evaluar y como valores el título que quieres mostrar.

Por ejemplo, este sería el array:

```
$arrTitles=array(
                    1=>"Título1",
                    2=>"Título2",
                    3=>"Título3",
                    4=>"Título4"

                );
```

Cuando el valor numérico sea `4` por ejemplo, basta con hacer esto:

```
echo $arrTitles[4];
```

**Salida:**

```
Título4
```

Puedes hacerlo con cualquier valor, por ejemplo, supongamos que es una variable:

```
$id=2;
echo $arrTitles[$id];
```

**Salida:**

```
Título2
```

---

### En el contexto de tu código

Sólo tendrías que hacer esto:

```
$theTitle=$arrTitles[$user->type];
```

Y tendrás en `$theTitle` el título correspondiente a la clave del valor actual.

Eso es lo que entendí que querías. Si no es eso, aclara mejor tu pregunta.

---

### EDICIÓN

Si he entendido bien... suponiendo tus datos así:

```
$arr=(object) array(
               (object) array("type"=>1,"name"=>"Martillo"),
               (object) array("type"=>1,"name"=>"Destornillador"),
               (object) array("type"=>2,"name"=>"Agua"),
               (object) array("type"=>2,"name"=>"Electricidad"),
               (object) array("type"=>3,"name"=>"Tren"),
               (object) array("type"=>4,"name"=>"Caterpilar")

           );
```

Y requiriendo imprimir un título adecuado una sola vez y cada vez que `type` cambie...

Podemos seguir haciendo uso de mi propuesta anterior, o sea, buscar el título en un array de títulos (a no ser que se puede tomar del mismo objeto). Hacemos una comparación del valor actual y del previo, si no son iguales imprimimos el título.

> **NÓTESE:** que aquí no hace falta preguntar cada vez por el valor de `type` y... estamos concatenado los valores en una variable para luego
>   imprimirla o enviarla a la vista según tu contexto.

#### Código completo:

```
$arr=(object) array(
               (object) array("type"=>1,"name"=>"Martillo"),
               (object) array("type"=>1,"name"=>"Destornillador"),
               (object) array("type"=>2,"name"=>"Agua"),
               (object) array("type"=>2,"name"=>"Electricidad"),
               (object) array("type"=>3,"name"=>"Tren"),
               (object) array("type"=>4,"name"=>"Caterpilar")

           );  

$arrTitles=array(
                    1=>"Herramientas",
                    2=>"Servicios",
                    3=>"Transportes",
                    4=>"Maquinarias"

                );

$prev=0;
$html="";
foreach ($arr as $user){
    $type=$user->type;
    if($type!==$prev){
       $html.="<h1>$arrTitles[$type]</h1>"; 
    }
    $html.="$user->name<br />";
    $prev=$user->type;
}
echo $html;
```

**Salida:**

```html
<h1>Herramientas</h1>
  Martillo<br />
  Destornillador<br />
  
<h1>Servicios</h1>
  Agua<br />
  Electricidad<br />
  
<h1>Transportes</h1>
  Tren<br />
  
<h1>Maquinarias</h1>
  Caterpilar<br />
```

Comment: Edité la pregunta para poder publicarla.